# Close dialog when "fb like" is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, facebook

I have jquery dialog on my website. It pops up when page is loaded. I want to give my dialog facebook functionality (like button).

Now I want to:

1. Dismiss dialog right after "Like" is clicked.
2. I don't want to show dialog if the user already "Liked" the page.

Please note I don't have any application ID associated with my page (when it comes back). Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Without using API and as FB is using iframe, that's not possible. Some bad workaround could be possible but would just give you indication that FB like button has been clicked, not that user effectively 'liked' your page. So best advice, use FB API

Comment: Oh, darn. I thought that was possible because if you "like" some page the button becomes different color. And if you revisit the site, that color remains. That means Facebook knows when you liked that site and when don't. So without API isn't possible? Damn..

Comment: But why not use tools exposed by FB API???

Comment: I will do that. It seems I have no other choice :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do that because of [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript). You can only do that with FB API like;

```
FB.api('/me/likes/your_page_id', {limit: 1}, function(response) { 
        if (response.data.length == 1) {
            // User already liked your page, do not open dialog
        } else {
            // $("#dialog").dialog(); User not liked your page           
        }
});
```

For detect when user click, you can use;

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
     function(response) {
          // User clicked like button
     }
);
```

You can create FB App [here](https://developers.facebook.com/)

Comment: Nice! So it's impossible to detect if user clicked on "Like" button. I would need that so I can close dialog...

Comment: Unfortunately. You can bind event to elements in iframe but it shouldn't be crossite.

Comment: I doubt that this works at all – because the SOP should prevent you from access HTML content from a different domain.

Comment: @CBroe you are right, I have forgot to mention about same origin policy. I have updated my answer